# Getting the real time number of rows in Mysql database using vb.net?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

How do I get the number of rows in my database in a real time? (e.g. if I add/delete a row of data it will be automatically showed in the textbox provided.)

this is my code:

```
Try
        connect.Open()
        da = New MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from tbl_book_info", connect)
        Dim row As String = "Select count(ISBN) from tbl_book_info"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(row, connect)
        Dim count As Integer = 0
        count = cmd.ExecuteScalar
        TextBox7.Text = count
        connect.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    da = New MySqlDataAdapter("Select count(ISBN) from tbl_book_info", connect)
    da.Fill(data)
```

but in the code above I have to close the form and open it again then the updated count of rows will be displayed. Thank you in advance for any help. :)

Comment: You dont need a DataAdapter to get a row count and you dont need to do it twice.   If you used a datatable for your app, you could just use `myDt.Rows.Count`.  Otherwise you will have to run the query to see how many rows, or keep a variable which you add to and decrement at you add and delete rows.

Comment: oh! I see.. thanks @Plutonix :)

Comment: It is a useless metric that usually gets implemented as a result of someone trying to show how clever they are.  When you go into the Library do you care or even wonder how many books are there?  No.  You *would* care about how many are checked out in your name, or are in your 'cart'.